# A sequence $(x_n)$ satisfying $0\leq x_n \leq \frac{1}{n}$ where $\sum(-1)^n x_n$ diverges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, divergent-series

A sequence $(x_n)$ satisfying $0\leq x_n \leq \frac{1}{n}$ where $\sum(-1)^n x_n$ diverges. This is a HW assignment problem for my undergrad real analysis class. I cannot come up with a sequence that is less than $1/n$ that diverges when summed as an alternating series. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Make sure the negative terms are much smaller than the positive ones (such that their sum converges). Then make the sum of the positive ones diverge.

Comment: The simplest example might be $$x_{2n}=\frac1{2n}\qquad x_{2n+1}=0$$ Along the same vein, one can also consider $$x_n=\frac1{2n}+\frac{(-1)^n}{2n\log(n+2)}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$
\text{Let}\;\, \large{{x_n}} = 
\begin{cases}
\small{\displaystyle{\frac{1}{n^2}}} & n \text{ is odd}\\[6pt]
\small{\displaystyle{\frac{1}{n}}} & n \text{ is even}\\
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: The example by "Did" (the "simplest example") is indeed simpler.